# Linux disable RAM Cache

Tags: debian, linux-kernel, memory, macintosh, virtual-memory

I'm running Debian stable with kernel 6.5 on an ARM M1 MacBook Air. The biggest issue is that RAM and VRAM are unified, and there is no particular way to even check how much of the used RAM is VRAM (as confirmed by the main Asahi Linux developer).

This causes the system to constantly hang when it is approaching less than 500 MiB free RAM. Theoretically, I can allocate memory using the `stress` program, and the kernel will kill it, but in practice any other program that's using too much memory ends up hanging the computer because the kernel does not account for the VRAM portion of the memory used. The kernel will kill programs using 200 MiB of RAM but leave ones using 3 GiB VRAM alone.

Creating a SWAP doesn't help either, because the moment the kernel starts swapping at all, the system hangs instantly without even time to write logs.

Is there a `sysctl` or a kernel parameter I can set to disable disk cache to RAM to keep more RAM free? I have to constantly run a `drop-caches` script to keep the system alive, I have it bound to a keyboard shortcut, and automatically run after some programs close.

The crashes sometimes happen with the most basic use (4 YouTube tabs open in Firefox and someone calls me on Telegram, or sends me a 60 second video which Telegram automatically downloads).

Any answer to such question I find is along the lines is "you're stupid, you don't need to disable caching, don't ever ask that again", no actual solution.

There's gotta be a better way than putting something like `"while true; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches ; sleep 60" &` into `/etc/rc.local`

I know this is not the right fix to the issue, but I need to stop the kernel from caching to have as much free RAM as possible.

Comment: If what you write is true, everyone would have the same problem. Neither Debian stable nor the M1 MacBook Air are very unusual systems, so you'd expect more reports. Do you have _anything_ that shows the actual behaviour? Logs when it happens etc?

Comment: @pipe like i said, system doesnt have time to write a log when it freezes. Sometimes just before, the kernel will complain that `kswapd` hangs. If you look at any Asahi linux forums, such as on the subreddit, that is the absolute #1 issue with it (everything else is compatibility with certain USB devices, audio, HDMI, basic stuff)

Comment: ive daily driven systems with unified memory before (Intel, ARM Pinebook pro), didnt have issues like this, but those video drivers are a lot more stable than the ones for M1 graphics
the Pinebook had unified memory and only 4G in total, so it's not even a fair comparison. The macbook has 8G

Comment: Have you [tried](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40337341/2344631) the kernel boot parameters [`mem`](https://mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/kernel-parameters.txt#2244) and/or [`memmap`](https://mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/kernel-parameters.txt#2281) to limit and define the amount of available physical memory?

Comment: @ChrisDavies is this for completely limiting how much physical ram the kernel will have access to? or for limiting regular RAM use and leave some as VRAM? Afaik, the kernel considers both as one, and it'll just limit the total making it worse

Comment: the other issue is the linux boot process on ARM macbooks is very weird and complex, it starts with apple's firmware > m1n1 (emulated a dev version of macos to run u-boot) > u-boot > grub-efi
There's a lot of passing hardware tables/trees (forget what its called) and containerization with the root filesystem for example (the ext4 exists on some obscure logical volume).
I don't think i'd be able to do much with restricting ram, considering that something as low level as grub already runs on like 4 abstraction levels below it

Comment: @NickBailuc as I understand it, `mem=` will limit the amount of physical memory that the kernel will use. So if you've got 8GB of shared RAM/VRAM you can decide that only 6GB is available to the kernel an the remainder is to be ignored

Answer (score 1):

I'm highly dubious about the provided rationale for what's going on.

AFAIK, modern Macbooks do not have special separate RAM regions for RAM and VRAM, it's a single unified chunk of memory which can be used by applications both for RAM and VRAM allocations, and it's the Linux kernel that should make sure RAM allocations don't eat into VRAM.

What you're describing sounds like a kernel bug that you should report to Asahi developers.

You could try using the `mem=MAX_RAM`, e.g. `mem=7G` (7 gigabytes) kernel boot option and see if it helps but I doubt it will.

Comment: please refer to https://www.reddit.com/r/AsahiLinux/comments/13ah4v2/comment/jj8dgza/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3

Comment: marcan is the top dev on Asahi Linux (porting Linux to Apple Silicon (ARM Macbooks and such). His comment:   


`There is another issue on Linux where GPU memory usage is not accounted per-app, so if an app eats all your RAM with GPU memory but little CPU memory, some other app is going to get killed first.

This is apparently a general Linux problem and affects ~all platforms equally (but it's more obvious with unified memory systems), with solutions proposed but nothing concrete yet.`

Comment: These are not the symptoms you described above.

Comment: @symcbean well it leads to that, for instance firefox is free to allocate itself 5 G of VRAM for a video while the kernel tries to kill plasmashell (like in one of the cases)
Here's some additional reads:

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/AsahiLinux/comments/155lkri/firefox_hangs_all_the_time/
https://www.reddit.com/r/AsahiLinux/comments/193tqd7/hot_pink_screen_flashes_when_running_many_firefox/
https://www.reddit.com/r/AsahiLinux/comments/19ahqru/memory_usage_in_asahi_higher_than_macos/
https://www.reddit.com/r/AsahiLinux/comments/1agm74j/ram_usage_problem_seriously/
https://www.reddit.com/r/AsahiLinux/comments/18frmdk/some_questions_about_ram_bt_and_firefox/

Comment: No it does not lead to the "system hanging". If it is OOM, the kernel and most of the components will still be running. Some parts you see on screen may disappear or become unresponsive. Check your logs / try the remediation I described.

Comment: how would you know if it does not lead to the system hanging, are you the one asking this? Like i said multiple times, the system doesnt have the time to write any logs. The system becomes unresponsive indefinitely, i cant even ssh into it to kill some apps or check `dmesg -w` or `htop`
no part of the system is responsive to anything, how is that not hanging.
And what use is "most of the components will still be running" if there is nothing i can do in the system in terms of input/output
I get to stare at a frozen screen of the last stuff that was displayed, thats about it

Comment: i tried out those `sysctl` configs after reading the kernel.org doc you linked, sounded promising
Unfortunately it crashed the system immediately, with some colorful errors
Heres the `journalctl` log (I removed the timestamps to make it easier to read, but most of it was within a second)
Trying to switch to and login from a TTY didnt work, and the systemd shutdown script also failed (i think the kernel just killed everything it could find)
Sorry for the pastebin, i didnt realize how shit this site became:
https://pastebin.com/7Fyz2qPt

Answer (score 0):

Like Artem I am very dubious about this. I am not specifically familiar with the MAC M1 architecture but have run Linux on lost of systems where the video uses main RAM - IME this has always been statically allocated long before any user processes start.

But assuming that your assertions are valid, I would try to solve the problem by a strict 0% [overcommit on memory](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vm/overcommit-accounting):

```
vm.overcommit_memory=2
vm.overcommit_ratio=0
```

(I suspect that both overcommit_ratio and overcommit_kbytes will not accept negative numbers - but this is definitely worth testing if the values above do not resolve).

**UPDATE**
Subsequent comments suggest this just the usual overcommit/OOMKiller issue. If this is the case then the suggestion I made here is the right way to fix the problem, although an overmmit ratio of 0 is perhaps over-zealous. **Check your logs**.

Comment: i understand, I've run Intel systems with their built-in HD graphics, and a much weaker pinebook pro with 4G unified memory (and now even pinephone pro same SoC)
but the problem only appears with heavy ram use, sometimes this can be having a large PDF open, sometimes a shitty site like youtube  which could use like 1.5G just for the 1 tab
It's gotten to the point where I'm constantly monitoring and mindful of everything that's running, which is not something I had to do with past computers tbh